# Facebook JS SDK Posted Photo is cropped

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook JS SDK to upload a photo and comment to my wall.  The photo keeps getting cropped.  How do I avoid getting photo cropped?  I have searched and cannot find any documentation on parameters that may be sent with the post command.  The image size I am posting is 800 X 620 pixels.

I suspect I am missing something very simple.  Any assistance will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
            var wallPost = {
            message: "My message goes here",
            picture: "http://SomeURLToAnImage.png",
            caption: "Some Caption",
            link: "http://SomeWebSite"
            };

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost, function (response) {
                       //Some code here
                }`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a small side note: You should use getLoginStatus on page load, not right after the API call. Here´s an article about how to use getLoginStatus and stuff: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

That being said, you are not uploading a picture right now, but creating a feed post with a link. You can just use the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) for that too, without the need to authorize the User. Or, if you really want to upload a picture, use the [/me/photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos#publish) endpoint instead.

About images sizes:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on
>   high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that
>   are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> ...
>
> Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible
>   to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

Source and more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. That does not solve my issue, however.  I may be asking the wrong thing.  I really want to post photos using the Graph API and js library from Facebook.  I may be trying to post to the wrong element.  Are there any examples out there from BEGINNING TO END of how to post - starting with the login, requesting proper permissions, getting the proper Id for the page or album to post to, then posting and finally logging off?  I find examples of one action, but they all assume one already has the way to retrieve another piece of data included in the example.

Comment: alright, i have edited my answer. i hope it helps, it´s a lot more detailed now.